# PHP how to convert \n to newline

Tags: php

How do I make a string that was declared using single quotes, evaluate `\n` as if it was declared using double quotes?

ie.

```
echo 'Line1\nLine2'; // Does not split.
echo "Line1\nLine2"; // It splits.

$s = 'A string declared using \n single quotes which I can\'t change...';
echo $s // I need this to have the split at \n
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should just be able to `str_replace` them to an actual newline:

```
$s = str_replace('\n', "\n", $s);
```

See https://3v4l.org/j0etV

If you're going to be displaying this as HTML, note that you'll also need to run it through `nl2br` (or if you're using a templating engine this might already be done for you)

Comment: If you already are doing a substr, and you know all new lines are \n and new all newlines are of \n type, I would go with replacing with br tag directly. Having 1 call instead of 2, while not having a huge difference fells bad. (And if you are doing this a lot of times those small calls do eat resources)

Comment: Theres a generic solution to work using another codes like: \n \s \t, \u0026 etc.. ?

Answer (score 2):

First you would have to repair your string.
Put `\'` instead `'`,
then you would have to use `str_replace()`

```
$s = 'A string declared using \n single quotes which I can\'t change...';
$s= str_replace('\n', "\n", $s);
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you replace  `\'` in `'`, using `str_replace()`

```
$s = 'A string declared using \n single quotes which I can\'t change...';
$s= str_replace('\n', "\n", $s);
```

or use following syntax

```
nl2br($s);
```